What happens if Trump decides not to attend his New York trial?
Trump is currently on trial for falsifying financial records. New York law apparently requires him to be present during the trial.
What happens if Trump decides he's not going to attend anyway? It looks like similar things have happened in the past - c.f. this Politics SE question where Trump aides defied subpoenas to testify - and nothing seems to have happened. But "nothing happens" seems like it makes the law toothless, and besides, Trump wouldn't be complaining about not being able to campaign while the trial is in progress.
I'm looking for a legal answer.

Looking at Trump's antics as an outsider - it would appear that he is continually and quite plainly acting in contempt of court eg by referring to a judge as "crooked" etc. But the courts take no action, other than to impose "gag orders", which raise yet further legal issues and  opportunity for delay. In short he makes a mockery of the judicial system. In the UK a judge has power to send a defendant to prison for contempt, where they remain until they "purge their contempt".

A bounty hunter gets paid over a hundred million dollars to fight Trump's Secret Service bodyguards.

@WS2 The US has much more stringent protections of free speech than pretty much anywhere. Publicly insulting, questioning, etc. the judge and prosecutor are protected speech.  The ability to criticize the government without fear of reprisal from said government is perhaps the number one goal of (our) freedom of speech. It's speech about witnesses, some evidence, and courtroom staff that might not be protected. Which he flaunts or pushes the limits of.

@zibadawatimmy Would a teenage black youth, with a string of convictions to his name,  accused of stealing a car, enjoy the same freedom of speech rights to call the judge crooked, insult the judge's daughter, and claim on social media that certain members of the jury had got it in for him?  Does the first amendment protect such people? Does America believe in freedom of speech to that degree?

@WS2 It's just like Trump says, we have a double standard. You don't see many black youth being indicted for fraud and campaign finance violations, it's a conspiracy against perfect former presidents who have had their re-election stolen from them.

I saw a pundit opining that Trump is deliberately goading the judge into putting him in jail for contempt. That will just make him seem like more of a martyr to his supporters.

@Barmar But isn't there some evidence that his support is likely to crater if he gets a criminal conviction?

@WS2 I think the expectation is it will kill his chances among independents and Republicans who are on the fence. But the people who believe his "witch hunt" rhetoric will double down. And what really matters is how many people in each camp are inspired to vote.

@Barmar the perfect former president is flawed on one thing: doesn't know what a witch hunt is. If a witch hunt was going on, there would be many people suspected of a particular crime, not one person suspected of many crimes.

@WeatherVane The metaphor doesn't imply that there are many "wiches". M-W defines it as "the searching out and deliberate harassment of those (such as political opponents) with unpopular views". While McCarthy's communist witch hunt was rounding up many, you can just attack a single person or small group. If the prosecution of Trump and his cronies were indeed a politically motivated sham, his characterization would be appropriate.

@Barmar historically, a witch hunt sought to find anyone who might be a witch (and perhaps set a test which is impossible to pass, say a ducking stool). So the McCarthy 'reds under the beds' is more true to the meaning of 'witch hunt'. And the point of a witch hunt is that you you don't know where they are. But DJT is already known. It's not as though plucked from obscurity as a scapegoat. He set it up himself.

@WeatherVane You're misunderstanding the metaphor. It's not just about  believing there are witches and searching for them (despite the word "hunt"). It's about wanting to persecute someone who does something you don't like (e.g. a woman who doesn't conform to social norms) and calling them a witch to get public support for punishing them. In McCarthy's case, witch == communist, and he cast this label on many liberals who were known to them.

@Barmar if he should be convicted on one or more of the charges by a fair court, was that a witch hunt? Are they persecuting someone they don't like, or is it a legal way to 'rope in' a maverick? Saying "it's witch hunt" is just noise.

@WeatherVane Of course it is, since practically everything Trump says is BS. It's not a witch hunt because there are good reasons to believe he's done the things he's accused of. Did you think I was agreeing with Trump's rhetoric?

Even the orange tan is BS.

Nitpick: Contrary to the media mouthings, he is not on trial for hush money payment, but for falsifying the records of that payment.

Yes, but …

If he waives his right, and the prosecution doesn’t object, the court may allow him not to be there.

If he’s too disruptive, he can be barred by the court.


I would expect that if Trump doesn’t want to be there, he’ll do the paperwork, the prosecution won’t object, and the court will allow it.

Counterpoint: they might instead lock him in a separate courtroom, muted and supervised, under Illinois v Allan, compare this question

This may be of interest: 2023-08-08: Does Donald Trump Have to Attend His Own Trial? | Lawfare

In addition to the options set forth in the correct answer of DaleM (and the correct comment to that answer by Trish), the Court can issue a warrant for his arrest and stop the trial in the meantime while he is arrested, if it wants to do so.
